# OpenCV || matchShapes findContours assertion failed

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching, shapes, contour

I am trying to match two contours with the matchShapes method but I always get assertion failed.
I know this must have something to do with the wrong Mat format but I can't seem to be able to solve it.

The findContours is working very well:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(incomingimage,
                 contours, 
                 CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                 CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

vector<vector<cv::Point> > contourstwo;
cv::findContours(incomingimagetwo,
                 contourstwo, 
                 CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                 CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

I get good output from these methods but then

```
matchShapes(Mat(contours), Mat(contourstwo), CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0);
```

returns

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

I am a bit in the dark here.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I also have to implement same work but I do not know much about opencv.Can you please provide code which you implemented for this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also beginner at openCV, but I just figure out how to solve this today 
(after many trial and error).
Please try this one

```
matchShapes(contours[0], contourstwo[0], CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The input to `matchShapes` according to the documentation should be of the type `vector<Point>` and not `vector<vector<Point> >`, as is the output of `findContours`, just iterate over each contour and pass it to `matchShapes`.